# How to get postgres schema from runinng query in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, database-schema

assume you do query on pg_stat_activity table and you get example result:

| datid | datname | pid | usesysid | usename | application_name | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port | backend_start | xact_start | query_start | state_change | wait_event_type | wait_event | state | backend_xid | backend_xmin | query | backend_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 7198 | 10 | rdsadmin |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | 7195 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16384 | rdsadmin | 32375 | 10 | rdsadmin | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16409 | c-t-s | 21143 | 16410 | c-t-s | c-t-s | 10.10.3.1 |  | 48037 | 2021-01-18 13:19:03 |  | 2021-01-18 13:31:23 | 2021-01-18 13:31:23 | Client | ClientRead | idle |  |  | COMMIT | client backend |

I would like to know on which schema the query `COMMIT` was executed?

My case is i have schema-based multitenancy and i would like to distinguish between schemas (tenants). We always make a single-schema queries, so we dont mix them. To achieve that we set `search_path` on each `getConnection` method invocation. Code is developed in java and we dont use schema names in queries, as it is always dynamic -- taken from current request context and set in `getConnection` method.

With current result I dont know which tenant (schema) is causing slow / long queries.

I have tried to select from pg_class by ids taken from pg_stat_activity but without luck.

So far the comments did not answer my problem, is that possible at all?

Comment: Queries is database-wide. Several schemas could be used in a single query.

Comment: I am asking on how to investigate which SCHEMA the query affects. The information is not present in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: `select * from pg_catalog.pg_class as c join information_schema.tables as t on (c.relname = t.table_name);` Which schema this query affects?

Comment: I am not sure if that is enough. It selects * about pg_class and joins to tables. But still dont have this information joined with pg_stat_activity.
Can we join that additionally with select * from pg_stat_activity; on PID or smth?

Comment: By this example query I trying to show that the single qoury could to use several schemas. Thus the right qustion should to be "How to get postgres schema(s) from runinng query" :) There is no separate information about used schema(s) in the `pg_stat_activity` view. Currently running queries text could be found in the `query` column (note: ["By default the query text is truncated at 1024 bytes"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW))

Comment: To catch executed queries the [logging system](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) is the best way IMO. When you have the query text then you could to execute `explain (verbose, format json) ...` and search for "Schema" keys.

Comment: `commit` isn't executed "on a schema". It's executed to end a transaction on a specific _database_. The transaction could have involved 200 tables in 42 schemas. Or just 1 table in 1 schema.

Comment: Ok, lets take other query as example: `SELECT * FROM PERSON` -- this one is executed on the schema, that was set to `search_path`. And now the question: how to get schema (or search_path) when you have the query PID?

Comment: How do you Execute this query ? With ADO ?

Comment: not sure what is ADO. I use java with hibernate and spring-boot based `@Repositories`. Queries are generated by spring-boot and some of them are defined by me using `@Query` annotation

Comment: `hibernate` and `ADO` are technology which give you a way to access DB.
I just edit your OP mostly by adding TAGS, this should help focus people with desired knowledge.